# How to convert string '6 dec 2019 9pm' to datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I used strptime() with format **'%d %a %Y %-Ip%'** but it's throwing the error stating "-I" is bad directive.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime('6 dec 2019 9pm')`

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Use `pd.to_datetime(date_col, format='%d %b %Y %I%p')`

Answer (score 0):

You have your time format wrong.  `%-Ip%` is not a valid format (should be `%I%p`), and `%a` is also incorrect for parsing `dec` (should be `%b%`).

The following example shows the output with the format `%d %b %Y %I%p`:

```
import time

struct_time = time.strptime("6 dec 2019 9pm", "%d %b %Y %I%p")
print(struct_time)
```

Output:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2019, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=6, tm_hour=21, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=4, tm_yday=340, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('6 dec 2019 9pm', '%d %b %Y %I%p')
```